# How to call the same method once for 2 events in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, touch

I am trying to create an app that works good both with a mouse and touchscreen. The click event didn't work good because as soon as I started dragging a little bit it didn't fire the click event.

So I created another event for `touchstart` but the problem on touchscreens is now that the `addPin` method gets called twice on a tap.

```
<div @touchstart="addPin('1')" @click="addPin('1')">
  1
</div>
```

I would prefer not to install any libraries for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you tap your screen , a click event will be executed. you have called same method twice using different events.
What you should do is determine if the input is a touch or a click event using javascript which has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37110501/detect-if-input-was-touched-tablet-or-clicked-mouse)